# Can I wake up PC/laptop on remote printing request?

Tags: networking, printer

I have an old Epson printer that does not have network adapter, only a USB socket. I have also a computer with network card. I could combine them to put this printer in my local network, but then I would need to keep the computer always up and running. That's definitely not economic.

Is there a way to wake up computer when printing request arrives? Something like Wake-on-LAN?

Or I am forced to use additional hardware?

Answer (score 1):

To send the print job, the computer would need to be turned on with the print service running... That said, you could set that computer to 'boot on LAN.' With this method, you would need to send a wake command to that PC to turn it on, wait for it to boot, then send the print job.

Not a very effective or efficient process by any means, but that is the only way I see it possible with that PC. What you could do, though, is buy a print server device [Newegg example printserver](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16833139009)

A $40 option to get that printer online.

Comment: Printservers work well with more expensive printers (those that support a language like PCL or PostScript). With low cost (GDI) printers, check the printserver's compatibility list. If your printer is not listed, it will not work.

Comment: Good advice. Additionally, at ~$40 for the printserver, I would just spend ~$50 more and get a network printer... they are dirt cheap now.

Comment: @Wesrock. Amen to that!